# A field containing $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Please give a field containing the complex number set $\mathbb{C}$ as its proper subfield.

Is the set of all complex coefficient rational functions a proper example? I wonder whether it is correct to regard a complex number as a polynamial (indeed one is a number and the other is a mapping).

Comment: $\mathbb C[x]$ is not a field...

Comment: Yes, constants are polynomials. You are mistaken when you suggest that a polynomial is a mapping: this is not so. It is true that every polynomial does give rise to a mapping, but the polynomial itself is not the mapping. I think if you clear up that misunderstanding you'll not have problems.

Comment: Just a note: requiring that a subfield $E$ of $F$ be a literal subset of $F$ is a very limiting position. Instead, it's better to consider an injective homomorphism $E\to F$ and identify $E$ with its image to say that $E$ is a subfield of $F$. Otherwise $\mathbb Z$ wouldn't be a subring of $\mathbb Q$, which wouldn't be a subfield of $\mathbb R$, which wouldn't be a subfield of $\mathbb C$, since by their usual constructions, their elements are completely different in a set theoretical sense: Complex numbers are pairs of reals, which are sets of rationals, which are sets of pairs of integers.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial ring $R[x]$ is *never* a field for any ring $R$, because $x$ does not have an inverse (or, if $R=\{0\}$, then $R[x]=\{0\}$ as well). You can consider the ring of rational functions $\Bbb C(x)$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{C}\subset \mathbb{C}(t)=\left\{\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}|\ f,g\in \mathbb{C}[t], g\not=0\right\}$$